# How to make an object bend and roll/twist at the same time?

Tags: rigging

I'm working on a game that has some very abstract creatures. One of them is a floating ball with a tail on it. The tail needs to roll around while its bending at the same time. Is this possible?

Think of a drill spinning around, then having it bend 45 degrees but still be spinning.

[image]

Comment: Probably is… I might use a double bone chain. That is, one set of bones, that do not have associated groups, to control the bending, and then patented to each bone (at its center/in the same location) is the bone that actually does the deforming, and it rotates. A single bendy bone, however, might do the whole thing for you. I would have to experiment to say for sure…

Comment: That creature looks like a tadpole ;-) - yes, double chain bones work. Just tested it. Bendy bones might work, too. But they only work inside Blender and you can't export them to a game engine as far as I know.

Comment: Does the tail turn continuously in one direction or does it go back and forth? Here's a test (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcGH.gif). I haven't tested yet what happens when you spin only the root bone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try with two bone chains as suggested. The *DEF* bones can be exported for a game engine.

[image: example animation]

Bone layer 1: deformation bones that do the twist (Y-rotation) and deform the mesh

- example: *DEF-Twist.001* → *DEF-Twist.002* → *DEF-Twist.003*

Bone layer 2: control bones for the bending (XZ-rotation) + optional IK target and pole

- example: *Bend.001* → *Bend.002* → *Bend.003* → *MCH-Bend end*

To bend the *DEF* bones in the right direction, add an *Inverse Kinematics* bone constraint to each of them. The target is the next control bone in the chain. The chain length is 1.

- example: *DEF-Twist.001* targets *Bend.002*, *DEF-Twist.002* targets *Bend.003*, and *DEF-Twist.001* targets *MCH-Bend end*

Don't forget to check `[X]` *Deform* on the *Bone Properties* tab for the DEF bones only.

If you have added an IK constraint to the control bone (*Bend.002*), you can set the *Influence* value to 0 and the *Bend* bones will behave like FK bones. This makes it easier the wag the tail left and right.

The *DEF* bone chain:
[image: DEF bones]

The control bone chain:
[image: control bones]